# How to access installation directory in post install script?

Tags: python

In my python package, post installation, there are some activities like permission changes for files needs to be performed, also the pip install will run with --target option, so post install script needs to know this installation directory path(passed with --target) so that permission changes can be done on the right path. my post install script will get expanded but the base is finding installation path inside post install

I tried with pkg_resources

```
from pkg_resources import resource_filename

class Post_Install(install):
    def run(self):
        print("Post install steps")
        install.run(self)
        package_dir = resource_filename('myproject',"config.json")
```

but during post installation, this is showing relative path like myproject/config.json and not sure this is the right way here(and this is not the path passed with --target).

this is my setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools.command.install import install
import os
import sys
from pkg_resources import resource_filename



class Post_Install(install):
    """Post installation activities"""
    def run(self):
        print("Post install steps")
        install.run(self)
        package_dir = resource_filename('myproject',"config.json")
        print("package dir {}".format(package_dir))

        from subprocess import call
        call([sys.executable, 'post_install.py',package_dir])



setup(name='myproject',
      version='1.1.0',
      author='methecoder',
      description='my python project'
      long_description=__doc__,
      packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests']),
      include_package_data=True,
      cmdclass={
        'install': Post_Install,
      },
      data_files =[ ('.', ['config.json']),
                    ('logs', []),
                    ],
      classifiers=[
          'Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
          'Environment :: Console',
          'Intended Audience :: End Users',
          'Intended Audience :: Developers',
          'Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows',
          'Operating System :: POSIX',
          'Programming Language :: Python',
          'Topic :: Communications :: Email',
          'Topic :: Office/Business',
          ]
    )

__author__ = 'methecoder'
```

my post install script

```
import os, sys
module_path = sys.argv[1]
print("from post_install.py module")
print("module path {}".format(module_path))
os.system("chmod 700 "+module_path+"/config.json")
print("changed permission")
```

suppose if my target direcotory is /home/user1/ then pip install would be,

```
$ pip install -t /home/user1/ myproject-1.1.0.tar.gz -v
```

then post install has to find /home/user1/ so that it can run chmod against necessary files.

Note : under the target directory the expected files are,

```
$ ls /home/user1/
myproject/
config.json
logs/
```